# How to enable huge page support in a Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker

I'm building a dockerfile for an app that requires huge page support

```
vm.nr_hugepages=128
```

inside `/etc/sysctl.conf`

How do I achieve that in a Dockerfile? I tried `run sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=128` but it didn't work apparently

Comment: The container is just a process in your Linux, so enabling this for your system has to be done outside of the container. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787506/how-to-mount-hugepages-inside-docker) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure HugeTlbPage on the host system and make sure it is mounted under `/dev/hugepages` directory.

Then give your container access to it by mapping the mount point to `/dev/hugepages` on the container.

You can bind mount a volume using `-v` option or `--device` to add a host device to the container. You’ll have docker run command like this:

```
# docker run -v /dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages ....
```

Or

```
# docker run --device=/dev/hugepages:/dev/hugepages ...
```